# SendFailedException.getValidUnsentAddresses()

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
MessagingException mex;
validUnsentAddress = ((SendFailedException)mex).getValidUnsentAddresses();
```

Above code snippet is not returning null, due to which my mail is not getting sent to the required recipient.

When and why `getValidUnsentAddresses();` returns `not null` value and what can be done to make it a `null`?

Comment: `SendFailedException` is thrown only when the message cannot be sent (server not responds, no connections, etc...). So, it's normal to return `non null` value. It may return `null` only if exception is thrown for other issue (intentionally throwed by your code for example)

Comment: If you have valid unsent address, something else is preventing your message from being sent.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  Or, what does [getInvalidAddresses](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/SendFailedException.html#getInvalidAddresses--) and [getMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html?is-external=true#getMessage--) show?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable the property *mail.smtp.reportsuccess* and depending on your use case *mail.smtp.sendpartial* too.

See here for the documentation:

https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#properties